# Can I sign transaction on backend using javascript on ImmutableX chain?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, immutability, erc20, layer-2

my question is basically written in title, but for more details, I am using node.js, I read immutableX documentation and review there SDKs, but nothing on javascript,
I want to sign the transaction in cloud function(firebase) on immutableX chain.
Main goal is to transfer ERC20 tokens from one wallet to another. In my case, token which I want to transfer is GODS.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never used ImmutableX but I think that for transferring ERC20 tokens you can use any library that can interact with Ethereum contracts like web3js

https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-send-erc20-token-with-web3-js-99ed040693ce

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thing is that, immutableX is layer 2 chain, So it has it's own APIs and SDKs, it's not a common case.